# NameError: global name 'QColor' is not defined

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want to change `QTextColor` in pyqt source code.  I found some solution using `setTextColor`.  With this code, now I get this error:

> `NameError: global name 'QColor' is not defined`

My code is

```python
    redcolor = QColor(255,0,0)
    self.textEdit.setTextColor(redcolor)
```

Comment: You need to import `QColor` to be able to use it. Not sure what version of `PyQt` you're using, but the following line should work: `from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor`. You need to add this to the top of the file. Alternatively, you can just `from PyQt5 import QtGui` and then do `QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: Yes now its working Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import only color module, use this code:

```python
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor
```

or, if you want to import all the modules related to PyQt4:

```python
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```